# "Google Now" swipe from Home button is not working in Marshmallow

Tags: google-now, 6.0-marshmallow

After updating to Marshmallow I was playing around with settings. I don't know what I changed, but now when I swipe from the bottom, "Google Now" is not coming.

I used to assign that with Greenify to lock the screen. How to get it back?

Comment: Please add your device information and which launcher do you use? and How did you update your device?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are actually 2 issues here:

1. No swipe from Home button gesture
2. Cannot change the action from Google Now to other apps (e.g Tasker, or Greenify)

The first issue is caused to accomodate a new feature called [Now on Tap](https://www.android.com/versions/marshmallow-6-0/). Now, instead of swiping the Home button, you just need to hold it to access Google Now screen (or "Now on Tap", [if enabled](http://www.droid-life.com/2015/07/09/google-includes-google-now-on-tap-in-android-m-preview-2-sort-of/)). AFAIK, this behaviour cannot be changed natively (enabling/disabling "Now on Tap" doesn't affect this).

The second issue is caused by the addition of explicit setting for assist app (before Marshmallow, [you need to clear defaults the app that you assign to before](http://www.androidauthority.com/replace-google-now-swipe-up-gesture-623375/)). The setting can be accessed from **Settings - Apps - Advanced (cog wheel icon) - Default Apps - Assist & voice input - Assist app**. By default, it is "Google App" (i.e. Google Now), and you can change to any apps that support this feature (i.e. Tasker, for my case).

Comment: If you change the assist app, you probably also need to turn off "Now on Tap" to prevent Google App throwing "Unfortunately, Google App has stopped".

Comment: But the thing is earlier Greenify used to ask whether to lock screen or hibernate and lock. Now its default is hibernate and lock

Comment: @sameer I can't say anything about how Greenify works in Marshmallow (I don't use the app). Probably you need to contact their developers for clarification (or ask another question here, but I'm not sure if it's answerable).

Answer (score 4):

Simply go to:

Settings > apps > setting icon > default apps > Assist & voice input > assist app

In there you will find a list of apps, you choose google, now  it will be selected. I use the home button to lock my phone with screen lock app. You should find greenify in there too,if you have it.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Actually in marshmallow, the swipe up gesture is replaced by the 'holding the home button' gesture. If you turn off the 'now on tap', the google now will launch if you hold the home button. I guess this is one of marshmallow's changelog...

Answer (score 0):

You can actually leave the 'now on tap' on and still get to google now by scrolling up from the 'now on tap' screen and tapping the 'G' button below.